# How to use XQuery functions to parse a specific part of the source XML?

Tags: xml, function, xquery

I need to create a DOT graph on the basis of the following XML file.

```
<layout>
 <layout-structure>
    <layout-root id="layout-root">
        <layout-chunk id="header-text">
             <layout-leaf xref="lay-1.01" location="row-1" area-ref="content"/>
             <layout-leaf xref="lay-1.02" location="row-2" area-ref="content"/>
        </layout-chunk>
        <layout-leaf xref="lay-1.03" location="row-3" area-ref="content"/>
    </layout-root>
    <layout-root id="layout-root-two">
        <layout-chunk id="header-text-two">
         <layout-leaf xref="lay-1.04"/>
             <layout-leaf xref="lay-1.05"/>
        </layout-chunk>
    </layout-root>
 </layout-structure>
<realization>
    <text xref="lay-1.01 lay-1.04"/>
    <text xref="lay-1.02 lay-1.05"/>
    <graphics xref="lay-1.03"/>
</realization>
<layout>
```

For this purpose, I use the following query to produce the DOT markup for each **layout-root** element in the XML:

```
declare variable $newline := '&#10;';
declare variable $dotgraphics := '[shape="box", style="filled", color="#b3c6ed"]';

declare function local:ref($root) {
 string-join((
  for $chunk in $root/layout-chunk
  return (
  concat('  "', $root/@id, '" -- "', $chunk/@id, '";', $newline),
  local:ref($chunk)
  ),
 local:leaf($root)), "")
 };

declare function local:leaf($root) {
 for $leaf in $root/layout-leaf
 return concat('  "', $root/@id, '" -- "', $leaf/@xref, '";', $newline)
};

declare function local:gfx($doc) {
for $layout-leafs in $doc//layout-leaf
let $graphics := $doc/realization//graphics
where $graphics[contains(@xref, $layout-leafs/@xref)]
return concat('"', $graphics/@xref, '" ', $dotgraphics, ';', $newline)
};

let $doc := doc("layout-data.xml")/layout
for $root in $doc/layout-structure/*
return string-join(('graph "', $root/@id, '" { ', $newline,
local:gfx($doc),local:ref($root),'}', $newline), "")
```

The result of the query for both **layout-root** elements is shown below:

```
graph "layout-root" { 
"lay-1.03" [shape="box", style="filled", color="#b3c6ed"];
"layout-root" -- "header-text";
"header-text" -- "lay-1.01";
"header-text" -- "lay-1.02";
"layout-root" -- "lay-1.03";
}
graph "layout-root-two" { 
"lay-1.03" [shape="box", style="filled", color="#b3c6ed"];
"layout-root-two" -- "header-text-two";
"header-text-two" -- "lay-1.04";
"header-text-two" -- "lay-1.05";
}
```

As you can see, the query uses the following function to change the colour and shape of the DOT markup, if an element is of the type **graphics**.

```
declare function local:gfx($doc) {
for $layout-leafs in $doc//layout-leaf
let $graphics := $doc/realization//graphics
where $graphics[contains(@xref, $layout-leafs/@xref)]
return concat('"', $graphics/@xref, '" ', $dotgraphics, ';', $newline)
};
```

However, this does not produce the wanted outcome, because it returns the line `"lay-1.03" [shape="box", style="filled", color="#b3c6ed"];` also for the second graph (named *layout-root-two*), although it should only appear in the first graph (named *layout-root*).

How should I modify the function, so that it checks for the **graphics** elements in case of each **layout-root** under **layout-structure**?

I have attempted to call the function using the variable *$root*, but this results in a static error.

The wanted outcome is displayed below:

```
graph "layout-root" { 
"lay-1.03" [shape="box", style="filled", color="#b3c6ed"];
"layout-root" -- "header-text";
"header-text" -- "lay-1.01";
"header-text" -- "lay-1.02";
"layout-root" -- "lay-1.03";
}
graph "layout-root-two" { 
"layout-root-two" -- "header-text-two";
"header-text-two" -- "lay-1.04";
"header-text-two" -- "lay-1.05";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the `realization`, which is not in the sub-tree of `$root`. Try passing in just the `graphics` node:

```
declare function local:gfx($root, $graphics) {
  for $layout-leafs in $root//layout-leaf
  where $graphics[contains(@xref, $layout-leafs/@xref)]
  return concat('"', $graphics/@xref, '" ', $dotgraphics, ';', $newline)
};

let $doc := doc("layout-data.xml")/layout,
    $graphics := $doc/realization//graphics
for $root in $doc/layout-structure/*
return string-join(('graph "', $root/@id, '" { ', $newline,
         local:gfx($root, $graphics),local:ref($root),'}', $newline), "")
```

Comment: Many thanks again @leo-worteler; this produces the wanted result!

Comment: Okay, I ran into a problem in my actual XML file where there are multiple instances of **graphics** elements. The resulting DOT markup merges all of the *xref* attributes of the **graphics** elements:

`"lay-1.01lay-1.05lay-1.07" [shape="box", style="filled", color="#b3c6ed"];`

They should naturally be separate:

`"lay-1.01" [shape="box", style="filled", color="#b3c6ed"];` ... etc.

Any idea what needs to be changed?